# Php Array values distribution near average

Tags: php, arrays, distribution

I'm working on some distribution of numbers from an array. I want to take the array with values in it and distribute them as evenly as possible. Example ->

values(7.50, 9, 4.50, 6.50, 4.75);

now the average is 6.45 but I only want to distribute them to 3 other arrays and they should get as near to 10.75 as possible beacuse array_sum($values) / 3; = 10.75

Now I would like if I could change the numbers of array to distribute the values to and like the add or remove values that should be distributed.

Please let me know if you have a great way to do this.

Best regards 
Wizzuriz

Comment: I beg your pardon, but please write your question in a more understandable form with a sample code or at least an example with a sample source array and result arrays to get a higher chance of answers

Comment: Agreed. I have no idea what you're trying to do after reading your question three times over.

Comment: Hmm.. How to explain it better. Please take a look at this website. http://mkln.ru/clash-of-clans/ here he distribute the units in 4 barraks. Now I would like to do something like that, I'ts just numbers insted of time.

Comment: I want to distribute the values in array_values(7.50, 9, 4.50, 6.50, 4.75); to 3 new arrays like this. array_1(9); array_2(7.50,4.50) array_3(6.50,4.50) But I know the values here and I would like to be able to distribute the values evenly in the 3 arrays without knowing the values.